# How can I draw a circle inside a Square C#

Tags: c#, graphics

```
float Radius1a = 100F;
float Radius1b = 100F;
PointF CentrePoint = new PointF(120, 120);
PointF Position1 = new PointF(CentrePoint.X - Radius1a, CentrePoint.Y - Radius1b);
RectangleF Rectangle1 = new RectangleF(Position1, new SizeF(Radius1a * 2, Radius1b * 2));
g.DrawEllipse(blackPen, Rectangle1);
```

I am trying to draw a circle inside a rectangle, this is what I have done so far but the output when the code is run just shows the circle and the circle inside the rectangle. How do I go about this?

Comment: `new RectangleF(....)` does not draw a rectangle - it just creates a struct to hold the rectangle data. To draw a rect, see: [`Graphics.FillRectangle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fillrectangle?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Comment: Please clarify "..shows the circle and the circle inside the rectangle". Does it show two circles or one? How is this different from what you want? Maybe a sketch or screenshot would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

I like to put graphics in an extension method because I tend to reuse a lot of them.

I think what you want is done with the following method

```
public static class Gdi
{
    public static void DrawCircleInsideSquare(this Graphics g, Pen pen, PointF center, float side)
    {
        RectangleF rectangle = new RectangleF(
            center.X - side / 2,
            center.Y - side / 2,
            side,
            side);

        g.DrawEllipse(pen, rectangle);
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, Rectangle.Round(rectangle));
    }
    public static void DrawCircleOutsideOfSquare(this Graphics g, Pen pen, PointF center, float side)
    {
        float diameter = (float)(side * Math.Sqrt(2));

        RectangleF circle = new RectangleF(
            center.X - diameter / 2,
            center.Y - diameter / 2,
            diameter,
            diameter);

        RectangleF rectangle = new RectangleF(
            center.X - side / 2,
            center.Y - side/ 2,
            side,
            side);

        g.DrawEllipse(pen, circle);
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, Rectangle.Round(rectangle));
    }
}
```

to be used as

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;

    PointF point1 = new PointF(100f, 100f);
    PointF point2 = new PointF(200f, 100f);
    float dia = 40f;
    Pen blackPen = Pens.Black;

    e.Graphics.DrawCircleInsideSquare(blackPen, point1, dia);
    e.Graphics.DrawCircleOutsideOfSquare(blackPen, point2, dia);
}
```

and here are the results:

[image: scr]

Answer (score -1):

float a = (MathF.PI * width * height / 4.0f;
float r = MathF.Sqrt(a / MathF.PI);

This is what I found last time I googled, instead of getting a circle around the box it draws one inside of it.
https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/circles-inscribed-in-squares

According to this all you need is the length of a side of the square, this is the diameter of the circle thus the radius is half that.

Comment: `Graphics.DrawEllipse` already takes care of this.  [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawellipse?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) say it _draws an ellipse defined by a bounding rectangle_.  So that means the circle would already be drawn inside the given square.  See a picture [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/ellipses-and-arcs-in-gdi?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: Does it work if you use the above version? a.... and then r = etc?